# Clone Div and Event Handlers Show/Hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I'm Cloning `div #Play_Start` and Under it I have events hide/show which will happen in particular within each cloned div. But on clone only first div events works.

Event : Select PLAY from dropdown, Div hide.

I want the events to fired on each div and within same cloned div.

My fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/kgm50e43/

```js
var count = 1;

function clone() {
  if (count < 5) {
    $(this).parents("#Play_Start").clone()
      .appendTo("#Clone_Play")
      .on('click', 'button.clone', clone)
    count++;
  } else {}
}
$("button.clone").on("click", clone);

function InputDropDown() {
  var MainNav = $('#Inputs-Control').val();
  if (MainNav == 1) {
    alert('hi');
    $('#Play_Start').children('.IconTest').hide();
  };
}
```

```css
.clone {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
.clonedInput {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Play_Start" class="col s12 l12 m12 First_sec clonedInput">
  <div class="col s3 l3 m3 input-field">
    <input type="text" id="tpOne" class="timepicker" placeholder="Start">
  </div>

  <div class="col s2 IconTest">
    asd
  </div>

  <div class="col s2 input-field">
    <select id="Inputs-Control" class="form-control" name="article()" onchange="InputDropDown();">
      <option value="0">Select</option>
      <option value="1">Play</option>
      <option value="2">Change</option>
      <option value="3">Pause</option>
      <option value="4">Stop</option>
      <option value="5">If</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col s2 m2 l2">
    <button class="clone btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light red counter_start_btn" onclick="clone();">
      <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    </button>

  </div>
  <div id="Clone_Play"></div>
```

Comment: I cannot understand your question correctly, are you saying the events after cloning is not getting fired?  what is the issue you are facing on your fiddle code?

Comment: Yes, After cloning events are not fired on cloned event. If you select play on drop down I hide the div. Which does not work on other cloned divs.

Comment: let me try and get back to you

Comment: Yes please. 
Thanx in Adv.

Comment: Plz check this https://jsfiddle.net/kgm50e43/1/

Comment: is this what you expected?

Comment: @DilipRajkumar it works but the events should fire for within the selected dropdown div. 
For now if you use any dropdown Play option it hides ASD from 1st div. 
So it should hide ASD in that div only. (this)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

https://jsfiddle.net/kgm50e43/1/

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.clone', clone);
$(document).on('change', '.form-control', function() {
    console.log($(this).val())
    var MainNav = $('.form-control').val();

    if (MainNav == 1) {
        alert('hi');
        $('#Play_Start').children('.IconTest').hide();
    };
});
```

Is this what you need.

The problem I found in your code:

> $('#Inputs-Control').val()

Id selector works only if you have one id on the page, its the way it supposed to be.  if not you should use class.

> $(document).on('change', '.form-control'

Also you should try to bind similar to above, which I usually follow because it works even the element going to be available future.

Hope it helps.

Comment: it hides only first div ASD, where in it should hide the element ASD within div you select drop down. So basically $(this) or .parent() might work???

Comment: I cannot understand your question Vinayak, you want to hide what.  If you hide the parent all its chidren will be hidden too..